# Upload large file to API and store it ti blob

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, garbage-collection, asp.net-core-webapi, dispose

I have simple web api controller with action

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Add(IFormFile file)
{
    var firmware = await _firmwareManager.Add(
        new FirmwareAddDto
        {
            Name = file?.FileName,
            Version = version,
            Data = file?.OpenReadStream()
        });

    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Created, firmware);
}
```

then in manager I have this code that store stream to azure blob storage

```
byte[] data = firmwareAddDto.Data.ToByteArray();
var blob = await _fileStorage.Add("filename", data);
```

Should I dispose something here? I'm going to upload a large files. Please advice if it will disposing correctly

Comment: Can you give more details about the type of the _fileStorage variable? And confirm if there are one overload with a stream as input?

Comment: No, there are no overload. It is `Task<File> Add(string name, byte[] data);`

Comment: But what is the class where that method belongs? Is it from a known library or it was made by you? Because if it is a large file I will advise you to copy from one stream to another so you don't have to load it into memory in the byte array.

Comment: it is some internal library (NuGet package). Yes, I can add overload to use stream. Where should I dispose it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large files, I advise you to copy the incoming stream into the outgoing stream, to avoid having to keep all file in memory inside the byte array.

Assuming that you have a method in the `fileStorage` that supports streams you can dispose it after you call the `Add` method. As you can see in the example bellow:

```
 using(var incomingStream = file.OpenReadStream())
 {
     var firmware = await _firmwareManager.Add(
        new FirmwareAddDto
        {
            Name = file?.FileName,
            Version = version,
            Data = incomingStream 
        });
     (...)
  }
```

then in the manager, you can call the method with the stream:

```
var blob = await _fileStorage.Add("filename", firmwareAddDto.Data);
```